# Нужен адаптивный кривой блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день, может кто показать как сделать вот такой кривой блок(см. на скрине), чтоб он еще нормально себя вел при изменении ширины экрана?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу то, что уже сами сделали и уточните, что конкретно у вас не получается.

Comment: @Pyramidhead та вот дело в том что я не знаю как это сделать, я пытался сделать упираясь на http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css но как-то очень все криво выходило

Comment: Тем не менее, stackoverflow - сообщество, которое готово помочь с вопросами по коду, который у вас уже есть. Если нужно что-то сделать "с нуля", то, боюсь, вы выбрали не тот ресурс.

Comment: Вот напишу щас ответ и меня минусуют)))

Comment: @Air страх ваш враг

Comment: Выложи сюда то, что не получилось и тебе помогут

Comment: Это не страх, это уважение к коллегам...

Comment: @Air причем тут это ?

Comment: @AlexeyAlpatov Нормально себя вел это тип адаптировался сам угол ? https://ibb.co/ek8G7m

Comment: @Даниил да, именно так

Comment: @AlexeyAlpatov делайте через befor, код добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
.block:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 320px; //Ширины блока
    height: 120px; //Нужная высота
    position: relative;
    background: url(/*сылка на кривой элемент, угол*/)no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom; //прижать элемент(угол) к низу блока 
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: То есть как я понял нужно сделать картинку в виде этого кривого элемента, да?

Comment: @AlexeyAlpatov в данном примере да, именно так. Вырежите из PSD этот угол и вставляйте как фон.

Comment: спасибо, за помощь!

Comment: @AlexeyAlpatov будут вопросы, пишите.  Всегда рад помочь.